# Reading cpu temperature Intel celeron R ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, temperature, lm-sensors

I know there are already a lot of questions like this, but non of the answers provided there could fix my problem. Hopefully I find an answer here. I try to read out my cpu temperature with lm-sensors on my ubuntu 10.04 LTS installation but I can't get to work. I did try the command

```
sensors-detect
```

several times but still nothing. My computer is an old PC with an Intel Celeron (R) @ 2.60 GHz. The odd thing is that the hdd temp is shown in the applet but when I type in the terminal

```
sensors
```

I get the error: "No sensors found! Make sure you loaded all the kernel drivers you need." I'm not really interested in the hdd temperature but I think it is strange that these sensors do work in the applet and not in the terminal.

This is the output that sensors-detect gives: http://pastebin.com/F4hVKaLU

Any suggestions?